# Taxonomist Badge

Tags: support, badges, taxonomist-badge

I recently got the taxonomist badge awarded for [acs](/questions/tagged/acs).
However, I am sure that I do not have used this tag. I did not even know what it stands for.

Is there a bug?

Comment: Is it possible that you accidentally created the tag due to a misspelling writing one of your questions which ended up being deleted?  That could explain why it doesn't show up.

Comment: Well, a typo leading to [tag:acs] would be one of [tag:asc], [tag:cas], [tag:csa], [tag:sca] or [tag:sac]. None of them fit to my questions either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a deleted question here: [Sphere rotation problem - points jump before turning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361650/sphere-rotation-problem-points-jump-before-turning) that you [added the tag to in the most recent edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5361650/revisions), the badge is behaving correctly...you created the [acs](/questions/tagged/acs) tag, you just can't see the question you did so on anymore...until 10k!

Comment: I can't even follow the links (at least until 10k). Interestingly enough that I created a tag I didn't know of.

Comment: @swegi: Just so you know what happened, it's a question that mentions "ACS" working with files with the ".acs" extension.  You edited it adding the [tag:acs] tag.