# Are there any other requirements for the Taxonomist badge?

Tags: support, tags, badges, data-explorer

Both [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/196683/tag-ownership-taxonomist) as well as [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/87763/how-close-are-you-to-a-taxonomist-badge) say that I am the creator of the [`soundtrack`](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soundtrack) tag on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/). But while the tag already has 82 questions associated to it, I haven't yet been awarded the *Taxonomist* badge.

So I wonder what is wrong. Are there any other requirements bound to that badge? Or maybe those queries are lying/wrong?

(I chose to post this here instead of [Movies & TV Meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/) since it seems more likely a problem (if any) with the general framework than that specific site.)

Comment: Just a note: that query is a complete guess and should never be taken as any kind of valid reason for you to have the badge. There are too many factors that can cause it to be inaccurate. I would suggest not even looking at it myself, simply because the chance of inaccuracy is so high.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query is wrong, you are just the first editor of the tag wiki.

<s>It was created way before, back in Dec 2, 2011 when [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/158/why-did-ennio-morricone-write-the-soundtrack-of-the-thing-1982-instead-of-jo) was asked.</s>

For some reason [this user got the badge](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=56), dunno why though and out of time to keep looking but it's not really relevant for your question. (might be due to a deleted question as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116977/152859))

Comment: Hmm, that first tagged question is indeed from me, but this other user was the creator of the site proposal. So maybe the first few tags are attributed to him, or maybe he proposed a bunch of initial tags (sounds strange, but who knows)?

Comment: @ChristianRau true, every site come with a bunch of predefined tags, good chance you're right. :-)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Then this seems like a reasonable possibility. Other than that a deleted question would be the only thing I could imagine. But this is hard to check, while I'm allowed to view deleted questions, they don't appear in any list.

Comment: If you would add that information from your previous comment (which I was absolutely unaware of) into the answer, I'd be inclined to take that as the correct solution to the problem.

Comment: @ChristianRau on second thought I'm not 100% sure about it, so will try to find official source first.

Comment: Hah! Once being able to check and list deleted questions, there indeed was a deleted question asked by that user *a day* before mine. Seems that was the problem then.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm pretty sure it's only per-site metas that come with predefined tags, not new main sites.